# Web2Py SmartGrid Headers

Tags: web2py

I'm trying to set the header labels in a SQLFORM SmartGrid.  I understand that the header argument must be a dictionary that specifies which table the setting refers to, but I'm having a hard time getting everything to line up as I would expect.

The below code uses the default header label.  I've tried various combinations of headers, but am struggling to get anything to have an effect.

**Model**

```
db.define_table('parent',
            Field('ParentName', type='string'),
            Field('ParentDescription', type='string'),
            format='%(ParentName)s'
           )

db.define_table('child',
                Field('ChildName', type='string'),
                Field('ChildDescription', type='string'),
                Field('Parent', 'reference parent')
               )
```

**Controller**

```
def index(): 
grid = SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.parent,
                         linked_tables=['child'],
                         user_signature=False,
                         headers={'parent':{'parent.parentName':'parent'}}
                        )

return dict(grid=grid)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field names are case sensitive. You have:

```
headers={'parent':{'parent.parentName':'parent'}}
```

`parentName` should be `ParentName`, matching the name in the field definition.

Also, an easier approach is just to specify a custom label for the field:

```
db.define_table('parent',
    Field('ParentName', label='parent', type='string'),
    ...)
```

or dynamically in a particular context:

```
db.parent.ParentName.label = 'parent'
```

Comment: Well, that is embarassing.  Thank you for the three solutions, I tried all three, and all worked.